# Synonym for "stay" as noun

Tags: word-request

If a person comes to some special place and stays there to rest for a while and does so often, several times a day, what appropriate word can I use for such multiple **stays**?

This place can be a cantina or a bar for instance, or even a club.

**Visits** isn't what I am looking for.

Comment: What's wrong with **stays**?  It's the most common choice.   https://www.google.com/search?q=%22several%20stays%20at%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Really? I thought it wasn't that popular.

Comment: Do you mean a lodging rented for some daytime hours? Or like some place where you take a break from jogging or driving? For driving, "rest area" or "rest stop" are commonly used.

Comment: @user3169 For daytime hours.

Comment: But where? Somewhere isn't enough.

Comment: @user3169 A certain place that a person visits to stay there for a while. He does it often, several times a day.

Comment: More context regarding what you are doing around the stops, and why you go to them, is needed. In general, I would use "taking a break". BTW, I wouldn't use *stay* in your context. You would *visit* a bar but *stay* at a hotel.

Comment: @user3169 No, I want something like comes'n'goes but with only "**comes**" as a noun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word you probably want is "**frequents**".

If you want to say they are a paying customer, maybe you could use "**patronize**".

Unlike *stays*, both of these are intransitive verbs so they need a direct object. eg:

> "She patronizes the local bar but he prefers to frequent the club."